# Add comments to photos in flickr using phpflickr

Tags: php, flickr, phpflickr

I got to know how to retrieve the comments on photo in my flickr account using phpflickr. But i am unable to add comment through the same to the photo. 
I tried:

`$phpflickr->photos_comments_addComment($photo_id,"TestCK");`

But i don't see my comment on the photo.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it...! I had to authorise my app on flickr and get the token by redirecting the page to getToken.php and store the token to $token.
Then I just had to add the lines: 
`

```
$f = new phpFlickr($apiKey, $apiSecret, true);
$f->setToken($token);
$f->auth();
$f->photos_comments_addComment($photoid,$comment);
```

:)